# RESTful @FormParam 400 Bad Request

Tags: java, rest, jersey, http-status-code-400, java-5

I have HTML form data and being passed to RESTful POST method. I have noticed that if @FormParam is declared as

```
@POST
public void commitProjects(
@FormParam("projectId")
        int projectId)
```

and if projectId is null or empty then when POST method is executed from browser, I am getting 
`400 Bad Request` error.

What could be reasons for this and what is the best approach to overcome such situation?

**Edit 1**

from browser

```
projectDesc=test&projectId=
```

and method is called from Jquery as

```
method: 'POST',
//dataType: "json",
contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
url: '/rest/projects',
```

**HTTP Header**

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8;q=0.6
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:625
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:JSESSIONID=0a0a0a0a231b787e42dd10d840d3b035d5998c574416
Host:xxxxxx:8987
Origin:http://xxxxx:8987
Referer:http://xxxxx:8987/project/test.jsp
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36
```

**Form Data**

```
projectDesc=test
projectId=
```

Comment: Show us how you `POST` a null or empty value. What is your HTML?

Comment: @LutzHorn I have included in Edit 1 of my question. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`null` or `empty` cannot be parsed as a 32–bit signed integer, and an HTTP 400 (Client Error) response is returned.

if  value does not exist, then  set a default as follows

```
@POST
public void commitProjects( 
    @DefaultValue("0") @FormParam("projectId") int projectId
    )
```

[More Details](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4867/6nga7f5np/index.html)

Comment: It seems  key-value  is not present in request, means form parameter is missing in the request

Comment: If user has not selected any value, form element will be null or empty.

Comment: My suggestion would be directly hit your rest service from your HTML form so that you can get the issues.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`@DefaultValue`](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/DefaultValue.html):

```
@POST
public void commitProjects(@FormParam("projectId") @DefaultValue("0") int projectId)
```

Comment: I have tried `@DefaultValue("0")`, however it didn't help to resolve the issue.